# Select specific text from specific span

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use python to scrape TripAdvisor and pull text from a specific span ---> `<span>138<span>` (without the Excellent)

```html
<label for="taplc_prodp13n_hr_sur_review_filter_controls_0_filterRating_5">
<div class="row_label">Excellent</div>
<span class="row_bar">
<span class="row_fill" style="width:65%;"></span>
</span>
<span>138<span>
</span></span></label>
```

This is my code thus far:

```python
for rating_all in moresoup.findAll('div',{'class':'col rating '}):
    for record in rating_all.findAll('li'):
        for rate1 in record.findAll('label',{'for':"taplc_prodp13n_hr_sur_review_filter_controls_0_filterRating_1"}):
                print(rate1.find('div',{'class':"row_label"}).text + ",\t")
                print(rate1.findAll('span'))
```

I tried using a subscript but it wouldn't let me. When I use the .text after the span it says there is no text, when I change it to find instead of find all it only finds the first span.

Comment: How are you subscripting/indexing? For me `rate1.findAll('span')[2].text` gives me `'138\n'`.

Comment: Oh! Wow that's great. I was putting the subscript after the findAll. So rate1.findAll[2]('span').text

Comment: Great! I have converted this to an answer so that it is easier for others to see the solution that worked for you, and so this shows up as a question with a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findAll` (or more commonly [`find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) - which does the same thing) returns a list of all `Tag` objects matching your filters. Even if there is only one matching `Tag` you will still get a one-item list: `[Tag]`.

Once you have the list of tags, you can get a single tag by indexing, e.g.:

```
soup.find_all('span')[0]
```

and you can get the text of one your tags with the `.text` attribute:

```
soup.find_all('span')[0].text
```

In your particular case, I was able to get the text `'138\n'` with:

```
rate1.findAll('span')[2].text
```